# Add, Subtract and Store Entry widget's input value (Tkinter, Python2.7)

Tags: python, tkinter

In this program, I am creating three entry widgets where I can put any values and connecting them by the equation 1st_entrybox - 2nd_entrybox + 3rd_entrybox. On clicking the button 'Total' I should get the total answer in the box called 'Energy Span'(the name is related to my project). But I'm not getting the answer. Could you please help?

Thanks in advance.

Here are my codes:

```
from __future__ import division
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()


btn1=Frame(root, width=600, height=600, bd=16, relief="raise")
btn1.pack(side=LEFT)

btn2=Frame(root, width=600, height=600, bd=16, relief="raise")
btn2.pack(side=LEFT)


def Sum():
    if var.get == 1:
        Qty1 = float(Trn.get())
        Qty2 = float(Intr.get())
        Qty3 = float(delG.get())
        Sumup = Qty1 - Qty2 + Qty3 
        Total.set(Sumup)

def Reset():
    Trn.set("0")
    Intr.set("0")
    delG.set("0")
    Total.set("0")


var = IntVar()
Trn = IntVar()
Intr = IntVar()
delG = IntVar()
Total = IntVar()


rb1 = Radiobutton(btn1, variable=var, value=1,
             font=('Helvetica',22,'bold')).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

lbl = Label(btn1, font=('Helvetica',22,'bold'), text="TS", 
  fg="black").grid(row=1, column=0)

ent = Entry(btn1, font=('Helvetica', 22, 'bold'), bd=4, width=13, bg= 
  "white",textvariable=Trn).grid(row=1, column=1)

lbl1 = Label(btn1, font=('Helvetica',22,'bold'), text="INT", fg="black", 
   bd=16).grid(row=2, column=0)

ent1 = Entry(btn1, font=('Helvetica', 22, 'bold'), bd=4, width=13, bg= 
  "white",textvariable=Intr).grid(row=2, column=1)

lbl2 = Label(btn1, font=('Helvetica',22,'bold'), text="Delta G", fg="black", 
   bd=16).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)

ent2 = Entry(btn1, font=('Helvetica', 22, 'bold'), bd=4, width=13, bg= "white",
          textvariable=delG).grid(row=3, column=1)

lblTotal = Label(btn1, font=('Helvetica', 22, 'bold'),text = "Energy Span", 
       fg="black", bd=16, justify="left")
lblTotal.grid(row=4, column=0)

lblans = Entry(btn1, font=('Helvetica',22,'bold'), bd=4, width=12, 
  bg="white", textvariable=Total, relief= "sunken").grid(row=5,column=1)

btnTotal = Button(btn2,pady=8, bd=8, fg="black", font=('Helvetica', 25, 
'bold'), width=16,height=2,text = "Total", bg="white", 
       command=Sum).grid(row=1, column=0) 

btnReset = Button(btn2,pady=8, bd=8, fg="black", font=('Helvetica', 25, 
 'bold'), width=16,height=2,text = "Reset", bg="white", 
       command=Reset).grid(row=2, column=0) 

root.mainloop()
```

An image of the output:[Simple calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PP1f8.png)

Comment: At a glance, `if var.get == 1` doesn't look right to me. All your other `get`s have parentheses, but this one doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call `.get` as you didn't put the parenthesis in. You need to change

```
var.get == 1
```

to

```
var.get() == 1
```

Comment: When I ran it in windows(IDLE) it worked, but while trying to run it in Linux it is giving me the following error. Can you please tell me why?                                                 
  if var.get() == 1:
TypeError: unbound method get() must be called with IntVar instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: @zih check the version of python in idle and the one in the terminal

Comment: they may be different

Comment: I have checked. They are the same.

Comment: maybe move `var = IntVar()` before `def Sum():`?

Comment: are you on ubuntu? if so have you installed `python-tk`

Comment: I am not in ubuntu. I am using Linux which is installed in university server.

Comment: im afraid i dont know the exact problem you have. sorry